# Store data as an encrypted MATLAB .mat file

Tags: matlab, load, save, protected, encryption

Is anyway to save a `.mat` file (contains database) as encrypted file. I want only my program (GUI) read these `.mat` files, not other users by directly opening files in MATLAB.

This link may halp but I'm not familiar with this page definitions. Can you describe it with more details? : [Serialize/Deserialize](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29457-serialize-deserialize)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that I have heard of, however there may be a way to protect it in a different way:

Due to lack of MWE, I came up with an example: I am assuming you know which variables you want to save. I have assumed here that variables A and B are to be saved. A is a double, B is a logical (different sizes). (cells need to be saved differently (cell by cell), let alone structs...!)

```
A=[1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8]; % your data (double) in your GUI
B=[0,1,1,0,1]==1; % your data (logical) in your GUI
pw='user2991243'; % make up a 'password' as variable in the GUI
% call this from your GUI function
function CreateHiddenData(A,B)
    fid=fopen('hiddendata.m','w');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', 'if strcmp(''user2991243'',pw)');
    % for a double
    str='A=[';
    for k=1:size(A,1)
        str=[str num2str(A(k,:)) ';'];
    end
    str=[str '];'];
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);
    % for a logical
    str='B=[';
    for k=1:size(B,1)
        str=[str num2str(B(k,:)) ';'];
    end
    str=[str ']==1;'];
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', str);
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', 'end');
    fclose(fid);
    pcode hiddendata
    delete('hiddendata.m')
end
```

For your program, you can directly call the .p file, it will loads the variable(s) into the workspace. (Although this will overwrite all variables with the same name)

Comment: Thank you for answer. Can you prepare a sample code for this method?

Comment: Is this method secure? What do you think about this? I am not familiar with this page definitions : http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29457-serialize-deserialize

Comment: How we can do this for cell array?, How we can read data after converting it to p-code? Thanks.

Comment: Cell array: you need to do this per cell individually. Of course, starting with 'C={' and ending with '};'. \\ For reading the data: simply call put the following as a line in your GUI: `hiddendata.p;`. This will load the data stored to the workspace (GUI workspace to be exact). \\ The data is protected, so the file can only be read by Matlab. As far as I know opening the file in e.g. notepad just give a bunch of 'mumbo-jumbo'.

Comment: Serialize does not encode the data. It simply saves it in bytes. Which can then be read back by Matlab again. \\ Also from the function description: "Limitations: No object can have more than 255 dimensions, and each dimension must be smaller than 2^32. Also structs cannot have more than 255 fields."

Comment: That was a good and precise description. If you add some codes for cell likes `%for a double` and `%for a logical` it is more useful. Thanks again.

Comment: and when I run the P-code in MATLAB, I have this error : `Error using open (line 162), cannot edit the P-file`. Thanks.

Comment: more information : for cell arrays we can't use `num2str`. we need a new function. + in some cells I don't have numbers. I have strings like names.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the function `pcode`. Maybe it could help you.

Comment: `P-code` can protect `M-file` not `Mat-File`. I'm searching for protecting `Mat-file`. Thank you anyway.